# Cannot update an address for a company

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4.4
I have a Company Entity that contains many address lines.
[image]
So CompanyId is the foreign key on the AddressLine.
I want to change the address for that company.
So my approach - maybe not the best one - is to delete the existing address lines and add the new address lines.
However I keep get errors such as "System.InvalidOperationException: The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null." and "System.InvalidOperationException: An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context."
The code is below;

```
public static void UpdateAddressLinesForCompany(int companyId, IList<AddressLine> lines)
{
    var company = Get(companyId);
    using (var db = new SherryGreenGroupEntities())
    {
        company.AddressLines.ToList().ForEach(x => db.AddressLines.DeleteObject(x));
        foreach (var address in lines.OrderBy(x => x.Position))
        {
            address.Created = DateTime.Now;
            address.CreatedBy = SessionObjects.LoggedInUser.EmployeeId;
            company.AddressLines.Add(address);
            //db.AddressLines.Attach(address);
            db.AddressLines.AddObject(address);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(address, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the definitions of `AddressLine` and the type of `company`.

Comment: Definition from EF shown

Comment: Need details (like what property/properties are set as `[key]`). With code first you could just use the class definitions, with model first it is not clear how you can show that in a useful manner (even reducing to a minimal re-create). I *expect* the key property/properties of the passed `AddressLine` instances have been set before they are added to the database, and their column in the database are identity. Ie. EF is expecting to populate the values when it adds the rows to the database.

Comment: I am using model first. AddressLineId is the primary key for AddressLine and that does not have a value until it is inserted. AddressLine contains a foreign key CompanyId which is the primary key for Company. CompanyId is set for each AddressLine in the collection for the parent company, which is the same for each AddressLine.

Comment: Yes, the primary keys in both Company and AddressLine are set to identity

Comment: What happens when `AddressLine.CompanyID` (and any navigation property) is its default value when you add to the `company.AddressLines` collection?

Comment: The CompanyId of the AddressLine is the CompanyId of the company that the address belongs to.
If I did not set it that way I would imagine the default would be zero. However that does not apply in this case.

Comment: When you add an entity to an association collection EF will set the association properties for you: do not do it yourself (EF cannot know if the old value is significant).

Comment: So are you suggesting I set CompanyId = 0 on the address line? How will the foreign key relationship between AddressLines and Company be maintained?

Comment: As I've said: when you add to the navigation property (`company.AddressLines`) EF will set the right properties.